# Python - Iterating through Dataframe and creating new column based on two other columns and string

Tags: python, pandas

This should be simple, but for some reason I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

I have a sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':('Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'David'), 'num':(1, 2, 3, 4)})
```

[image]

I want to create a new column called `link` where if the value in `name` is 'Nick', then the `link` value would be some text + the `num` column value.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
df['link'] = np.where(df.name == "Nick","https://" + str(df.num), '')
```

But instead of the first row being:

```
0, Nick, 1, "https://1"
```

It is:

```
0, Nick, 1, "https://0    1\n1    2\n2    3\n3    4\nName: num, dtype: int64"
```

Which means it is using the whole `num` column, rather the row.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? And on a side note, I have to do this for millions of rows, any suggestions of the most efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.num.astype(str)`, not `str(df.num)`:

```
df['link'] = np.where(df.name=="Nick", "https://" + df.num.astype(str), '')
```

output:

```
    name  num       link
0   Nick    1  https://1
1   Nick    2  https://2
2   Nick    3  https://3
3  David    4
```

##### Why?

`df.num.astype(str)` converts each item to a string:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: num, dtype: object
```

`str(df.num)` converts to the string representation of the Series object, which gets applied to all rows by broadcasting:

```
'0    1\n1    2\n2    3\n3    4\nName: num, dtype: int64'
```

Comment: THANK YOU!. Very quick too!

I am guessing I was turning the column into a string in my version, whereas you are saying use the column where each value is now a string. Super!